# Parse.com and Parse Server Local data Store (is making app to don't callBack)

Tags: android, parse-platform

i'm using Parse server and all is working fine except when i enable localdatastore, most

1 saveInBackroud stop working and also

2 SignUpInBackgroud is singin up a new user but, is not calling back, and it's being impossible to stop a progressDialog

3 Also not saving usersession on signup

```
Parse.Configuration config = new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
.addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseLogInterceptor()) .addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseStethoInterceptor())
.applicationId(PARSE_APP_ID_DEV) .clientKey(PARSE_CLIENT_DEV)
.server(PARSE_SERVER_URL) .enableLocalDataStore() .build();

Parse.initialize(config);
```

Any help ?

Comment: Not related but keep in mind that parse is going out of business as of next January: https://parse.com/pricing

Comment: but why do you need the localdatastore in first place... I was using it and it worked fine with all these functions you have written here

Comment: @MazelTov That's the problem, if i desable localdata store, all is working fine, in both my own parse server and parse.com 

Can you please gist me the code you used to store data and then load it from local data store ?